# Gulp task to SSH and then mysqldump

Tags: ssh, gulp, devops

So I've got this scenario where I have separate Web server and MySQL server, and I can only connect to the MySQL server from the web server.

So basically everytime I have to go like:

- step 1: 'ssh -i ~/somecert.pem ubuntu@1.2.3.4'
- step 2: 'mysqldump -u root -p'password' -h 6.7.8.9 database_name > output.sql'

I'm new to gulp and my aim was to create a task that could automate all this, so running one gulp task would automatically deliver me the SQL file.

This would make the developer life a lot easier since it would just take a command to download the latest db dump.

This is where I got so far (gulpfile.js):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Run: 'gulp download-db' to get latest SQL dump from production //
// File will be put under the 'dumps' folder                      //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Load stuff
'use strict'
var gulp = require('gulp')
var GulpSSH = require('gulp-ssh')
var fs = require('fs');
// Function to get home path
function getUserHome() {
  return process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE;
}
var homepath = getUserHome();

///////////////////////////////////////
// SETTINGS (change if needed)       //
///////////////////////////////////////


var config = {

  // SSH connection
  host: '1.2.3.4',
  port: 22,
  username: 'ubuntu',
  //password: '1337p4ssw0rd', // Uncomment if needed
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync( homepath + '/certs/somecert.pem'), // Uncomment if needed

  // MySQL connection
  db_host: 'localhost',
  db_name: 'clients_db',
  db_username: 'root',
  db_password: 'dbp4ssw0rd',

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Core script, don't need to touch from here //
////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Set up SSH connector
var gulpSSH = new GulpSSH({
  ignoreErrors: true,
  sshConfig: config
})

// Run the mysqldump
gulp.task('download-db', function(){
  return gulpSSH
    // runs the mysql dump
    .exec(['mysqldump -u '+config.db_username+' -p\''+config.db_password+'\' -h '+config.db_host+' '+config.db_name+''], {filePath: 'dump.sql'})
    // pipes output into local folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dumps'))
})

// Run search/replace "optional"
```

SSH into the web server runs fine, but I have an issue when trying to get the mysqldump, I'm getting this message:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Warning:
```

If I try the same mysqldump command manually from the server SSH, I get:

```
Warning: mysqldump: unknown variable 'loose-local-infile=1'
```

Followed by the correct mylsql dump info.

So I think this warning message is messing up my script, I would like to ignore warnings in cases like this, but don't know how to do it or if it's possible.

Also I read that using the password directly in the command line is not really good practice.

Ideally, I would like to have all the config vars loaded from another file, but this is my first gulp task and not really familiar with how I would do that.

Can someone with experience in Gulp orient me towards a good way of getting this thing done? Or do you think I shouldn't be using Gulp for this at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, that warning message was preventing the gulp task from finalizing, I got rid of it by commenting the: `loose-local-infile=1` From `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`